# using ubuntu on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm curious about ways to install non-standard Linux(specifically Ubuntu) OS's on EC2. Is there any way I can install Ubuntu 10.04 on Ubuntu EC2 instead of the 12.10 which seems to be available? Any trustworthy online images you could point me to?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the offical AMIs from Canonical listed on the [Alestic.com](http://www.alestic.com) website. Select your desired region with the select box on the top right and find the AMI IDs for the Ubuntu versions back to 8.04.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go to Community AMIs, check (select) the Ubuntu from the left side menu and put the version (10.04) in the search box, press enter.
This should provide you the AMIs with 10.04 in their names and probably the Ubuntu version you want.